# Custom function for label in QGIS Server GetPrint request

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-server, qgis-custom-function, getprint

I'm trying use GetPrint request with QGIS Server and I find feature that you can assign value of function to label (with id) ex.

`http://qgis.local/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/home/mario/wms.qgs&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&SRS=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetPrint&LAYERS=wms&STYLES=&FORMAT=png&TEMPLATE=Template1&field1=[%25 now() %25]`

[image: Result of GetPrint request with function in label expression]

From QGIS 2.8 there is [possibility to make your own function](http://www.qgis.org/pl/site/forusers/visualchangelog28/index.html#feature-custom-expression-function-editor) so I try with built-in custom function `func(value1)`

`http://qgis.local/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/home/mario/wms.qgs&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&SRS=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetPrint&LAYERS=wms&STYLES=&FORMAT=png&TEMPLATE=Template1&field1=[%25 func('a') %25]`
[image: Result of GetPrint request with custom function in label expression]

Is there way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The custom registered functions don't get propagated at the server level. One way to make the server know about your custom function is to write a server plugin and register your expression in the class factory.

More details here:
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Custom-python-expressions-in-QGIS-Server-td5362875.html